# Terraform reduce the amount of loops at the moment of generating a JSON

Tags: terraform

I have this terraform code that is generating me this JSON.

```
{
     host = {
          path = "/xxxx/yyyy"
     }
     name = "NAME"
}
```

Currently it's working, but I have 3 loops, consider it not efficient, wondering if I can reduce it to 2 or probably 1 loop? Or this isn't possible.

My first loop validates that container_mounts isn't empty. Don't want to generate it, if that comes empty. The second and the third is specific for getting the information as container_mounts is a map of strings.

```
variable "container_mounts" {
  type = map(string)
   default = { "app/data" = "/xxxx/yyyyy" }
}

  json = jsonencode(
    [
      for i in range(length(var.container_mounts)) :
      {
        name = [for sourceVolume in keys(var.container_mounts) :
        replace(substr(sourceVolume, 1, length(sourceVolume)), "/", "-")][0]
        host = {
          sourcePath = [for key, value in var.container_mounts : value][0]
        }
      }
    ]
  )
```

Is there a way to improve it? I assume that yes, but running into different scenarios were it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

So after talking with a friend, looks I complicated my life doing what I did.

```
json = jsonencode(
    [
      for key, value in var.container_mounts :{
        host = { "sourcePath" = value }
        name = replace(substr(key, 1, length(key)), "/", "-")
      }
    ]
  )
```

It can be done only with one loop.